# using overflow hidden, show a partial element when the children are too large for container

Tags: css, overflow

For a visual, please visit this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rR8Hh/

The effect I am trying to achieve is that, in this example, the left side of the 5th `div.child` should be visible, just to the right of the 4th child div.

Instead, there is a line break and so none of this element can be seen. Using `white-space: nowrap` has no effect.

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="child">4</div>
    <div class="child">5</div>
    <div class="child">6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent{
    height:90px;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:3px solid black;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.child{
    float:left;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    margin:5px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

I know I've achieved my desired effect before, but I can't seem to figure out how I did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly crude but working way of doing this is to wrap the child divs in another div with a large width. For example:

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    width:9999px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="child">1</div>
        <!-- etc -->
    </div> 
</div>
```

I only set the width to `9999` because I didn't know how many child elements you have. The width could be calculated and set when the server outputs the page or you could use a small piece of javascript (`wrapper width = number of child elements * child outer width`).

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/rR8Hh/4/